# A jazzy one-liner

Tags: word, wordplay

> Standing next in turn in good mood; finished "Straight, No Chaser" with a fast tempo.

What the Thelonious are we describing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was trying to find something quite complicated, but soon got the feeling that something was

> **up**.

In particular:

> Standing **up**,
>  You're **up** (next in turn)
>  Not feeling **down** (in good mood) (trying to avoid unfortunate mix-ups by this choice of words)
>  time's **up** (finished)
>  Straight **up** (served with no ice and no chaser)
>  **up**tempo  (with a fast tempo)

And since we are clearly on the theme of music here, I'm guessing [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) is the final answer that OP was trying to sneak past us.

Comment: The most elaborate Rick Roll I've ever seen.

Comment: @John I think I might burn that video onto a DVD with the label from the Pixar movie referenced in this answer and then give it to someone as a gag gift...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman that's so hideously evil I'm getting goosebumps :-)